# How do I split string on delimiters but exclude other strings

Tags: regex, python-2.7, delimiter

I have this string that I want to split on periods:

```
j = 'you can get it cheaper than $20.99. shop at amazon.com. hurry before prices go up.'
```

This is the result I'd like:

```
['you can get it cheaper than $20.99. ', 'shop at amazon.com.', ' hurry before prices go up.']
```

I split on every lowercase letter with a period before it and any number with period and whitespace after it.

```
x = []
sentences = re.split(r'([a-z]\.|\d\.\s)', j)
sentence_endings = sentences[1::2]
for position in range(len(sentences)):
        if sentences[position] in sentence_endings:
            x.append(sentences[position -1] + sentences[position])
```

Printing x gives me:

```
['you can get it cheaper than $20.99. ', 'shop at amazon.', 'com.', ' hurry before prices go up.']
```

I want "amazon.com" to be one string, so I instructed the regex to ignore ".com" with `re.split(r'([a-z]\.|\d\.\s)[^.com]', j)`
but that doesn't get me the result I want. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-regex option could be to use [`nltk.sent_tokenize()`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize):

```
>>> import nltk
>>> j = 'you can get it cheaper than $20.99. shop at amazon.com. hurry before prices go up.'
>>> nltk.sent_tokenize(j)
['you can get it cheaper than $20.99.', 'shop at amazon.com.', 'hurry before prices go up.']
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple regex  to split on periods followed by a space could be [`\.\s`](https://regex101.com/r/cO8mP9/4).

You can use a lookbehind to preserve the period in the splits: [`(?<=\.)\s`](https://regex101.com/r/cO8mP9/3)

And if you want to use a splitting approach to get just "amazon.com" from your string, you can try [`.*(?=amazon.com)|(?<=amazon.com).*`](https://regex101.com/r/cO8mP9/5)

Comment: `re.split(r'(?<=\.)\s', s)`